# Connecting last and first value of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers, say `list= [0,1,0,1,0]`. I have to check for each element i in list whether its equal to its previous and the element after it and if it is, change its value to the previous one. I presented this task as:

```
 i-1=x

 i+1=y

 for i in list: 

    if x=y and i!=x 

     i=x

      elif x!=y 

        i=i
```

But I need to connect the first and the last element in list, so that if `i=list[0]`: `x=list[4]` (and `y=list[2]`). My idea was to define another loop like this:

```
if i=list[0]

  x=list[4]
```

But when i execute the program it writes that `x=list[0]` is "syntax error: invalid syntax". First, I am not quite sure why is this: I was thinking that I didn't define x (but I did!), or I maybe didn't define it in the right place (I am not sure where I should define it then). On the other hand, is this the way to connect last and first value of list?

Comment: A single equals sign is assignment, not comparison, and you're missing a colon.

Comment: Thanks for editing and answer! ;) How do i generally make parts of code look like code here?

Comment: It's markdown, you need four spaces at the start of each line for a code block. You can select the pasted code and hit Ctrl-K or the `{}` button. See the formatting help (via the `?` button) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that does exactly what you asked.

```
test=[0,1,0,1,0]   # don't use 'list' as variable name
for j in range(len(test)):   # j=index of current
  i = (j-1) % len(test)      # i=index of previous
  k = (j+1) % len(test)      # k = index of next
  if test[i] == test[k]:     # equal to previous and next
    test[j] = test[i]        # change to previous
print(test)
```

Comment: Exactly! Right now, i managed to execute code, and it just gives me lists with same values, even though it is obvious that it went through all ''i's''.

As your code, i dont understand why do you need %len (test)?

Comment: The `% len(test)` is called modulo arithmetic (search for that term).  It is exactly what allow to connect the first and last values.  For example, when j equals 0, then i would be -1 (this would still work in python, since it accepts -1 as index), writing `(j-1) % 5` brings the index value within 0 to 4.  However, when j equals to the last index (when j=4  in your example), k would be 5 and result in an "out of bounds" error.  Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html?highlight=indexing#what-s-a-negative-index

Comment: Okay, i think this is exactly what i need. I have just one more question:
You sad that a should have code that works (quote)" whether it is equal to the preceding value or the one after it". I am not quite sure if you understood what is my problem. So, let me expalin again (maybe i dont understand you). The current value needs to change ONLY IF the preceding and the one after it are equal. If these to are not equal, the current one has to stay the same.

Comment: Okay, with this clarification you should write `if test[i] == test[k]:`.   Your code should work then. I tried with your example, and it gave `0,0,0,0,0`.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this reall helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
i-1=x

 i+1=y

 for i in list: 

    if x==y and i!=x :

     i=x

      elif x!=y 

        i=i
```

`=` means assignment whereas `==` means equality test.  And the colon `:` in python defines the beginning of a scope (indented) so you need `:' after an`if` to define its scope block.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! :)

Comment: @JelenaCvijan . You're welcome.  :Accept my answer by clicking on the check mark to the left so others will be similarly helped, thanks.